# cakephp : how can i store a encrypted data into db and then decrypt it through key

Tags: cakephp, encryption, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, encryption-asymmetric

i am working on a Cakephp 2.3 I'm trying to encrypt my data which i am storing into db, so I searched for a way to do this. I found this [http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/utoxin/2009/08/01/cryptable-behaviore](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/utoxin/2009/08/01/cryptable-behavior)

i dont know its the best behviour or not or if some one has the better behavior then please suggest me ..

so the problem here is i have read all the details in the link but still i cant get to know that how can i save my fields encrypted into db

for example i have a function in controller which is saving data

```
  $this->Messages->save($this->request->data);
```

how can i save this data in encrypted in db

and then my **modal**

```
 public function getAllMessages($id){

    return  $this->find('all',array(
        'order'=> array( 'idTextMessage DESC'),
        'conditions' => array('User_id' => $id)));
}
```

how can i decrypt this data

i have done this but didnt work

```
class Message extends AppModel{
public $useTable = 'textmessage';

public $actsAs = array( 
    'Cryptable' => array( 

        'fields' => array( 
            'mobileNo',
             'body' 
        ) 
    ) 
);
```

Comment: You can use the `beforeSave` and `afterFind` function callbacks in your model to encrypt/decrypt the fields required.

Comment: @derek ... not working Derek.. again data is not going encrypted in my tables

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't used that plugin, but it's from 2009, so it's pretty old now. I wouldn't put too much faith in it.

It's easy to decrypt/encrypt using Cake's `Security::rijndael`, without using a plugin (note that the [mcrypt php extension](https://www.php.net/mcrypt) will need to be installed - but it may well be installed already).

First, in your model, add an array of the fields you want encrypted:

```
public $encryptedFields = array('mobile', 'body');
```

Then, implement a beforeSave like this:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    foreach($this->encryptedFields as $fieldName){
        if(!empty($this->data[$this->alias][$fieldName])){
            $this->data[$this->alias][$fieldName] = Security::rijndael($this->data[$this->alias][$fieldName], Configure::read('Security.key'), 'encrypt');
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Your afterFind method should be pretty much the same, except it should decrypt rather than encrypt:

```
public function afterFind($results = array()) {
    foreach($this->encryptedFields as $fieldName){
        if(!empty($results[$this->alias][$fieldName])){
            $results[$this->alias][$fieldName] = Security::rijndael($results[$this->alias][$fieldName], Configure::read('Security.key'), 'decrypt');
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Note I haven't tested all of that code - it's hacked together from bits and pieces in one of my own apps. But it should put you on the right track.

Comment: thankyou so much ..i think i almost near to my solution .. well i have tried ur code and exactly i have pasted ur code but now  the data is going empty into db .. ?

Comment: Have you got the mcrypt extension installed? Can you use Security::rijndael at all, even for a simple case? If you put debug($data); at the end of your beforeSave, right before returning true, what do you get?

Comment: its already installed on my server mcrypt.. let me check the data

Comment: i have done this   if(!empty($this->data[$this->alias][$fieldName])){
            $this->data[$this->alias][$fieldName] = Security::rijndael($this->data[$this->alias][$fieldName], Configure::read('Security.key'), 'encrypt');
        }
    } echo $this->data;
    return true;

Comment: i got the error on the browser saying that You cannot use an empty key for Security::rijndael() [CORE\Cake\Utility\Security.php, line 220]          and the result of data is coming this  "Array" is printing on the browser

Comment: well thankyou i found the solution ... can you tell me how to make this more powerfull ..or its is best for securing my data

Comment: well last think the data is not decrypting

Comment: This is the way you want to go, we use a similar method where I work. You just have to be careful about the exact data structure being passed to `afterFind()` because sometimes it will come from direct model calls, and sometimes it will come from relation calls (`hasMany()` etc) and the structure is different.

Comment: well thankyou joshua for putting me on the write direction .. i think something is wrong in your code in afterfind  function .. if you find the problem then please share to me ... anyway ... thank you very much ... because without you i think i am not able to encrypt or decrypt data like that  instead i have to stuck with some plugins .. thankyou so much

Answer (score -1):

well the after find functions wasn't working dont know why .. so i do this .. may b it helps someone else ..

```
public function beforeSave($options=array()) {
 if  ( isset ( $this -> data [ $this -> alias ] [ 'email' ] ) )  {
     $this -> data [ $this -> alias ] [ 'email' ]  =  Security::rijndael($this->data[$this->alias]['email'], Configure::read('Security.key'), 'encrypt');
    }
    if  ( isset ( $this -> data [ $this -> alias ] [ 'address' ] ) )  {
     $this -> data [ $this -> alias ] [ 'address' ]  =  Crypt :: encrypt ( $this -> Data [ $this -> alias ] [ 'address' ] ) ;
    }

}
```

afterFind Function

```
 public function afterFind($results = array(),$primary = false) {

   foreach  ( $results  as  $key  =>  $Val )  {
         if  ( isset ( $Val [ 'User' ] ) )  {
             if  ( array_key_exists ( 'email' ,  $Val [ 'User' ] ) )  {
                 $results [ $key ] [ 'User' ] [ 'email' ]  = Security::rijndael($Val[ 'User' ] [ 'email' ], Configure::read('Security.key'), 'decrypt');

            }
 if  ( array_key_exists ( 'address' ,  $Val [ 'User' ] ) )  {
                 $results [ $key ] [ 'User' ] [ 'email' ]  = Security::rijndael($Val[ 'User' ] [ 'address' ], Configure::read('Security.key'), 'decrypt');

            }

        }
    }return $results;


 }
```

source: http://be-hase.com/php/239/